# Using library code (specifically curand) with CUDALink

Tags: cudalink, gpu

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
gausvSource = "
#include <curand_kernel.h>
__global__ void gausv( float *out  )
{
    curandState_t curand_state;
    curand_init ( 0, 0, 0, &curand_state );
    *out = curand_normal( &curand_state );
}";
CUDAFunctionLoad[gausvSource, "gausv", {{"Float", _, "Output"}}, 256]
```

yields a series of errors like:

> curand_kernel.h(558): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" 
>   linkage

Wrapping the include, the function, or the whole thing in `extern "C" { }` changes the message to:

> CUDALink encountered an invalid program.

So, how does one correctly use library code with `CUDALink`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler accepts the following code :

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
gausvSource = "
}
#include <curand_kernel.h>
extern \"C\" {
__global__ void gausv( float *out  )
{
    curandState_t curand_state;
    curand_init ( 0, 0, 0, &curand_state );
    *out = curand_normal( &curand_state );
}";
cudaFun=CUDAFunctionLoad[gausvSource, "gausv", {{"Float", _, "Output"}}, 256]
```

The function is callable :

```
x=1.
cudaFun[{x}]
```

> {{0.00459315}}

I have not tested further.

The idea is that Mathematica encloses the whole CUDA-C program in a `extern { }`, so one can exit it with a `}` (the third line of the code above).

Comment: my "answer" is uniquely for information, not sure that's a good advice

Comment: Good answer. It was crashing my kernel until I rebooted Ubuntu. Now it's working. CUDAlink seems a bit fragile. Thank you.