# CURAND library import error to Mathematica/Wolfram 12.1

Tags: random, cuda

I used Mathematica/wolfram 12.1 IDE and  installed CUDA toolkit 10.2. All installed correct. I try to use library CURAND with #include   with random integer generator on CUDA, but get a error:

`Message[CUDAFunctionLoad::cmperr, "PATH_CUDA_TOOLKIT/.../include\\curand_kernel.h: \ error: this declaration may not have extern \"C\" linkage"]`

What is wrong, with my code?

```
secondKernelCode = "
  #include<curand_kernel.h> // problem here !!!
  // my kernel
  __device__ float f(float x) {
     return tanf(x);
  }

  __global__ void secondKernel(float * a, float * b, float * c, float* d, mint nIterations) {
  int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  //....
  }";

secondKernel = CUDAFunctionLoad[secondKernelCode, "secondKernel", {{"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, _Integer}, 16]
```

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170856/5467)

Comment: See also the Wolfram Community, a question from John Doty

Comment: Thanks! It is good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's worked. Extern "C" makes a function-name in mathematica have 'C' linkage. Code show below.**

```
(*CUDA-function code*)
secondKernelCode = "
}
 #include <curand_kernel.h>
 extern \"C\" {
 __device__ float f(float x) {
  return tanf(x);
}

__global__ void secondKernel(float * a, float * b, float * c, float* d, mint nIterations) {
 int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
 curandState_t curand_state;
  curand_init ( 0, 0, 0, &curand_state );
  *a = curand_normal( &curand_state );
  *b= curand_normal( &curand_state );
  *c = curand_normal( &curand_state );
  *d = curand_normal( &curand_state );
}";

(*CUDA function load*)
secondKernel = CUDAFunctionLoad[secondKernelCode, "secondKernel", {{"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, _Integer}, 16]
```

Out[1] = CUDAFunction["<>", "secondKernel", {{"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, {"Float"}, "Integer64"}]

The function call from mathematica

```
a = 10;
b = 1;
c = 1;
d = 1;
secondKernel[{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, 1]
```

Out[2]={{0.292537}, {-0.718359}, {0.958011}, {0.633711}}

Comment: That is same problem, by @john-doty [Curand integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170856/using-library-code-specifically-curand-with-cudalink)